# Get data with PHP, Ionic and angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to do, what I think is a pretty easy thing, but I cant get it to work.
I'm trying to get some simple data in a app created with Ionic.

I'm new to Angularjs, so maybe I'm doing it wrong:-)

My controller code:

```
.controller('StarterCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
 $http.get("ajax/getMembers.php").success(function(data){

 $scope.tasks = data
 alert(data);
 })
```

})

And my php code

```
<?
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$arrayTest = array('test');
echo json_encode($arrayTest);
```

The problem is that the result i'm getting is the whole php code in html.
So the result in my alert is this:

```
<?
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$arrayTest = array('test');
echo json_encode($arrayTest);
```

Can somebody see what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks - Andreas

Comment: Do you have a server to run PHP from?

Answer (score 0):

SORRY!!! A stupid mistake from my side. I thougt that Ionic maybe could run PHP fil in git bash, but ofcourse not!

Comment: No, no, you need a server. :)